# PayUMoney- Android Remove postCheckout pages

Tags: android, checkout, payumoney

I have successfully integrated PayUMoney in my Android project but after Success/Failure of any payment we received the post Checkout pages from PayUMoney like below

[image: Failure screen]
[image: Success screen]

Now on click of provided button I received my payment info in `onActivityResult` method.

**Is there any way to skip these pages and directly get the results in onActivityResult?**

Code Implemented (PayUMoney Config Object):

```
PayUmoneyConfig payUmoneyConfig = PayUmoneyConfig.getInstance();
        payUmoneyConfig.setPayUmoneyActivityTitle("Payments");
        payUmoneyConfig.disableExitConfirmation(true);

        payUmoneyConfig.setDoneButtonText("Continue");
        txnId = "txn_"+System.currentTimeMillis();
        PayUmoneySdkInitializer.PaymentParam.Builder builder = new 

    PayUmoneySdkInitializer.PaymentParam.Builder();
            builder.setAmount(balance)
                    .setTxnId(txnId)
                    .setPhone(new SharedPreferencesUtils(ActivityPayUMoney.this).getUserPhone())
                    .setProductName("Product Name")
                    .setFirstName(new SharedPreferencesUtils(ActivityPayUMoney.this).getUserName())
                    .setEmail(new SharedPreferencesUtils(ActivityPayUMoney.this).getUserEmail())
                    .setsUrl("https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php")
                    .setfUrl("https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php")
                    .setUdf1("")
                    .setUdf2("")
                    .setUdf3("")
                    .setUdf4("")
                    .setUdf5("")
                    .setUdf6("")
                    .setUdf7("")
                    .setUdf8("")
                    .setUdf9("")
                    .setUdf10("")
                    .setIsDebug(new SharedPreferencesUtils(ActivityPayUMoney.this).getPayUMoneyDebug())
                    .setKey(new SharedPreferencesUtils(ActivityPayUMoney.this).getPayMerchantKey())
                    .setMerchantId(new SharedPreferencesUtils(ActivityPayUMoney.this).getPayMerchantSalt());
```

Gradle implemented

```
implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.6.0'
```

Comment: two possible Answers are
1- If it auto-generated by **PayUMoney** then no 
2- If it's not auto-generated then by using fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it
I was just doing a small mistake

just replace

```
    PayUmoneyFlowManager.startPayUMoneyFlow(mPaymentParams, 
ActivityPayUMoney.this, R.style.PayUMoney, false);
```

with

```
    PayUmoneyFlowManager.startPayUMoneyFlow(mPaymentParams, 
ActivityPayUMoney.this, R.style.PayUMoney, true);
```